# Quartz job not restarting in java web

Tags: java, jsf, quartz-scheduler

I am implementing a module to take the screenshot of logged in user after every 3 minutes.

This module works fine

But the problem I am facing is that whenever i logged in the user the job starts as it intends to do, but on the logout I shuts down the scheduler. But now the next time i try to login back now scheduler initialized but job isn't starting. I need to redeploy project again for next run.

Here is my `LoginBean.java` class from where I am starting the job.

```
package com.viremp.beans;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.viremp.component.HandleHobs;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8650636789236091591L;
private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginBean.class);

private String username;

private String password;

private String error;

private boolean visible = false;

private HandleHobs handleHobs;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

/*
 * public LoginBean() { try { if (handleHobs != null &&
 * !handleHobs.isJobStoredScreenShotIsStarted()) { handleHobs = new
 * HandleHobs(); } } catch (Exception e) { LOGGER.error("error init job", e); }
 * 
 * }
 */

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        if (handleHobs == null || !handleHobs.isJobStoredScreenShotIsStarted()) {
            handleHobs = new HandleHobs();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("error init job", e);
    }

}

public void login() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException, AWTException {
    // String un = "a";
    // String pw = "b";
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
    // Login login = new Login();
    // boolean isLoggedIn = login.LoginUser(username, password);
    try {
        request.login(username, password);

        handleHobs.startJobStoredScreenShot(username);
        externalContext
                .redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/faces/Success.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        this.error = getErrorParam(fc);

        setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("not equal.. " + error);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*
     * 
     * if (isLoggedIn) { System.out.println("equal"); externalContext
     * .redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath() +
     * "/faces/Success.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"); } else {
     * 
     * FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); this.error =
     * getErrorParam(fc);
     * 
     * setVisible(true); System.out.println("not equal.. " + error);
     * 
     * }
     */
}

public String getErrorParam(FacesContext fc) {

    Map<String, String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    return params.get("error1");

}
public logout(){
      handleHobs.shutdownJobStoredScreenShot();
      ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    externalContext.invalidateSession();
    externalContext.redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
}
```

And here is my `HandleHobs.java` class which is for handling job, [sorry for the wrong class name, it should be HandleJobs.java]

```
package com.viremp.component;

import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;

import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class HandleHobs {

private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HandleHobs.class);

private static JobDetail job;

private static Scheduler scheduler;
String email;

public HandleHobs(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

private static Trigger trigger;

{
    try {

        if (job == null && scheduler == null && trigger == null) {
            LOGGER.info("initializing job");

            job = (JobDetail) newJob(JobStoredScreenShot.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();

            trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "group1").startNow()
                    .withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(5).repeatForever()).build();

            scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
            LOGGER.info("init successsful");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("fail to init variables for job", e);
    }
}

public HandleHobs() {

}

public void startJobStoredScreenShot(String email) {
    try {
        this.email = email;
        JobStoredScreenShot jss = new JobStoredScreenShot();
        jss.setEmail(email);
        if (scheduler != null && !scheduler.isStarted()) {

            Scheduler scheduler1 = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            System.out.println("here..... " + email);
            scheduler1.getContext().put("email", email);
            System.out.println("and here..... " + email);

            scheduler.start();
        }
        LOGGER.info("init successsful");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("fail to init job JobStoredScreenShot", e);
    }
}

public void shutdownJobStoredScreenShot() {
    try {
        if (scheduler.isStarted()) {
            scheduler.shutdown();
        }
        LOGGER.info("shutdown successsful");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("fail to init job JobStoredScreenShot", e);
    }
}

public boolean isJobStoredScreenShotIsStarted() {
    boolean isStarted = false;
    try {

        if (scheduler != null) {
            isStarted = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("fail get isTarted", e);
    }
    return isStarted;
}

}
```

And here it is my `JobStoredScreenShot.java` class

```
package com.viremp.component;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.quartz.SchedulerContext;

import com.viremp.core.domain.Screenshot;
import com.viremp.core.domain.User;
import com.viremp.core.repository.ScreenshotRepository;
import com.viremp.core.repository.UserRepository;
import com.viremp.core.repository.impl.ScreenshotRepositoryImpl;
import com.viremp.core.repository.impl.UserRepositoryImpl;

public class JobStoredScreenShot implements Job {

String email;
User user = new User();

public void setEmail(String Email) {

    this.email = Email;
    System.out.println("in job stored class email is: " + email);

    user.setEmail(email);
}

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {

    try {

        SchedulerContext schedulerContext = arg0.getScheduler().getContext();
        // Below line gets the value from context.
        // Just get it and cast it in to correct type
        String email = (String) schedulerContext.get("email");
        System.out.println(email);
        BufferedImage image = new Robot()
                .createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
        baos.flush();
        byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();

        System.out.println("in execute " + user.getEmail() + ".................: " + email);
        UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepositoryImpl();
        user = userRepository.getUserByEmail(email);
        System.out.println("USER IS: " + user.getUsername() + " id is : " + user.getId());
        // byte[] buffer = (((DataBufferByte)
        // (image).getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData());
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        Screenshot screenshot = new Screenshot();
        screenshot.setInput(inputStream);
        screenshot.setScreenshotName(user.getUsername());
        screenshot.setUser(new User());
        screenshot.getUser().setId(user.getId());
        screenshot.setScreenShotTime(java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate));
        System.out.println("id is " + 1l);
        ScreenshotRepository screenshotRepository = new ScreenshotRepositoryImpl();
        screenshotRepository.create(screenshot);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("d:\\screenshot.png"));

        System.out.println("screenshot taken");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Please Help, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by making `job` and `scheduler` `null` after shutting down the `scheduler`.

Here is the working code of `HandleHobs.java`

```````````````````````
package com.viremp.component;

import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;

import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class HandleHobs {
private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HandleHobs.class);

private static JobDetail job;

private static Scheduler scheduler;
String email;

// SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();

public HandleHobs(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

private static Trigger trigger;

{
    try {

        LOGGER.info("initializing job");

        job = (JobDetail) newJob(JobStoredScreenShot.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();

        trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "group1").startNow()
                .withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(5).repeatForever()).build();

        scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        LOGGER.info("init successsful 1");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("fail to init variables for job", e);
    }
}

public HandleHobs() {

}

public void startJobStoredScreenShot(String email) {
    try {
        System.out.println("yaar ma aa gaya hun");
        this.email = email;
        JobStoredScreenShot jss = new JobStoredScreenShot();
        jss.setEmail(email);
        if (scheduler != null && !scheduler.isStarted()) {

            Scheduler scheduler1 = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            System.out.println("here..... " + email);
            scheduler1.getContext().put("email", email);
            System.out.println("and here..... " + email);
            scheduler.start();

        }
        LOGGER.info("init successsful");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("fail to init job JobStoredScreenShot", e);
    }
}

public void shutdownJobStoredScreenShot() {
    try {
        if (scheduler.isStarted()) {
            // JobExecutionContext context = new JobExecutionContext();
            // JobKey key = context.getJobDetail().getKey();
            // String jobId = key.getName();
            // System.out.println("```````````````````NAME``````````````````````" + jobId);
            // flag = true;

            scheduler.shutdown();
            scheduler = null;  //i made it null here
            job = null; // i made it null here
        }
        LOGGER.info("shutdown successsful");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("fail to init job JobStoredScreenShot", e);
    }
}

public boolean isJobStoredScreenShotIsStarted() {
    boolean isStarted = false;
    try {

        if (scheduler != null) {
            isStarted = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("fail get isTarted", e);
    }
    return isStarted;
}

}
```````````````````````

And this is my `LoginBean.java` from where I am initiating the job.

```
package com.viremp.beans;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.viremp.component.HandleHobs;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8650636789236091591L;

private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginBean.class);

private String username;

private String password;

private String error;

private boolean visible = false;

private HandleHobs handleHobs;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

/*
 * public LoginBean() { try { if (handleHobs != null &&
 * !handleHobs.isJobStoredScreenShotIsStarted()) { handleHobs = new
 * HandleHobs(); } } catch (Exception e) { LOGGER.error("error init job", e); }
 * 
 * }
 */

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {

        handleHobs = new HandleHobs();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("error init job", e);
    }

}

public void login() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException, AWTException {
    // String un = "a";
    // String pw = "b";
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
    // Login login = new Login();
    // boolean isLoggedIn = login.LoginUser(username, password);
    try {
        request.login(username, password);

        handleHobs.startJobStoredScreenShot(username);
        externalContext
                .redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/faces/Success.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        this.error = getErrorParam(fc);

        setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("not equal.. " + error);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*
     * 
     * if (isLoggedIn) { System.out.println("equal"); externalContext
     * .redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath() +
     * "/faces/Success.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"); } else {
     * 
     * FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); this.error =
     * getErrorParam(fc);
     * 
     * setVisible(true); System.out.println("not equal.. " + error);
     * 
     * }
     */
}

public void logout() {

    System.out.println("in logotu");
    handleHobs.shutdownJobStoredScreenShot();
    this.handleHobs = null; // here i also made null
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    externalContext.invalidateSession();
    try {
        externalContext
                .redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/faces/Login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getErrorParam(FacesContext fc) {

    Map<String, String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    return params.get("error1");

}
}
```

Actually after shutting down the jobs did shutdown the scheduler but did not empty the job and scheduler, so on next login the scheduler and job keeps the value so that the job was not starting again, so i just made the values null on shutdown.